# How to write apex class or trigger for changing the opportunity name to lead name after lead is converted

Tags: apex, trigger, salesforce1-app

When a lead is converted to opportunity , the field opportunity name is set with account name default. But I want to change the opportunity name to lead name using apex class or trigger. How can do this?

Comment: can you please add the code?

Comment: I Have added complete code along with handler class try it

Comment: right answer is sfdcfox answer. you can see in answer Lists. one typing mistake happend thats why you got the error. credit  goes to that answer. not for  my answer . that what i mentioned in earlier comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any error checking or other complicated setup, the following should work:

```
trigger setLeadNameToOpportunity on Lead(after update) {
  Opportunity[] records = new Opportunity[0];
  for(Lead leadRecord: Trigger.new) {
    if(leadRecord.ConvertedOpportunityId != null) {
      records.add(
        new Opportunity(
          Id=leadRecord.ConvertedOpportunityId, 
          Name=leadRecord.Name
        )
      ):
    }
  }
  update records;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You use .setOpportunityName(String oppName), something like this:

```
Database.LeadConvert lc = new Database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(myLead.id);

lc.setOpportunityName('myOpportunityName');

Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
```

Sets the name of the opportunity to create. If no name is specified, this value defaults to the company name of the lead.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dml_convertLead.htm#apex_Database_LeadConvert_setOpportunityName

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily achieved by a Process Builder instead of a trigger, which saves you the hassle of writing a unit test.

In the Process Builder, you trigger the node on Lead.IsConverted being set to true, and then

[image: Lead Criteria]

you set the Name of the Converted Opportunity Id to whatever you want, for instance the Lead Name as you suggested.

[image: Process Update Action]

Comment: Why do you have that requirement? Are you looking to streamline your logic into one kind of tool? In that case, you might want to look at using a proper trigger framework.

Comment: We have already 4+ process builder and while deployment it will be difficult so the requirement was to create in apex class or trigger

Comment: You can combine multiple use cases in 1 process by using the 'Evaluate the next criteria' option.

Comment: I combined both the process now, but i have an error. In first criteria i gave lead.isConverted false and in second criteria i gave Lead.isConverted true..  Will it works

Comment: What was the error?

Comment: Your lead field is missing a field mapping for the fields, and REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING

Comment: I think that is an error you should be able to figure out right? There are some required fields on Lead that you aren't setting. Or required fields on the converted account/contact/opportunity that you aren't mapping from a field on Lead with a value.

Comment: All fields are mapped correctly, eventhough facing the same error.

Comment: Then you aren't filling in a value for one of the lead fields that are mapped to required account/contact/opportunity fields.

Answer (score -1):

Trigger code:

```
 trigger setLeadNameToOpportunity on Lead(after update) {
 if(trigger.isUpdate&&trigger.isAfter){   //context variable
  callYouApexClass.StaticMethod(Trigger.new);   //for your understanding 
    //keeping your class name & method Name as  its
}
}
```

> callYouApexClass - Provide proper name convention
>
> StaticMethod  - Method Name

//Create a  class

```
public class callYouApexClass{
public static void StaticMethod(List<Lead>LeadList){
 List<Opportunity>opportunityList=new List<Opportunity>();
for(Lead leadRecord:LeadList){
if(leadRecord.ConvertedOpportunityId != null) {
 Opportunity op=new Opportunity();
  op.Name=leadRecord.Name;
 op.Id=leadRecord.ConvertedOpportunityId;
 opportunityList.add(op);
 }
 update opportunityList;
}
```

Comment: Error: Compile Error: Invalid loop variable type expected SObject was Lead at line 4 column 1 @Annappa PH

Comment: i have updated the answer check it

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. The code has no error, but while converting lead some error is shown like this.( " Your lead is missing a field mapping for the fields. For help, talk with your admin or see Map Custom Lead Fields for Lead Conversion in Salesforce Help.")

Comment: check this knowledge article for that error :  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315255&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1

Comment: Okay sure sir. One last doubt will this change the opportunity name to lead name

Comment: Trigger does that

Comment: who had down the down vote. please explain whats the problem in answer?... moderator please note this as well. then dont say that im not behaving well in community and dont ban me !!!...i am already highlighting this things from long time